# FusionCharts - Adding images to a scatter chart(XML,C# MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, fusioncharts

I am very new to fusioncharts and am struggling to be able to add images to my Fusionchart. Please forgive me, I dont even really know how I am supposed to ask this question, so If there is data that you want me to add that would help, please let me know.

I currently have it working by plotting the x and y points and setting the anchorsides and anchorradius, but I want to replace these with an image and I have no idea how to.

Here is a portion that I am using a foreach to populate the x and y axis :

```
strXML += "<dataset  drawline= '0' seriesname= 'Peak' color= '#ff0000' anchorsides= '3' anchorradius= '5' anchorbgcolor= '#ff0000' anchorbordercolor= '#ff0000'>";

        foreach (var cat in CalcList)
        {
            if (cat.isPeak)
            {
                strXML += "<set y='" + cat.Elevation + "' x='" + cat.Accumulated_Length + "'/>";
            }
        }

        strXML += "</dataset>";
```

Ive gone onto the FusionChart site and I see they do something like this :

```
<annotations width="500" height="300" autoscale="1">
    <annotationgroup id="user-images" xscale_="20" yscale_="20">
        <annotation id="butterFinger-icon" type="image" url="http://static.fusioncharts.com/sampledata/images/butterFinger.png" x="$xaxis.label.0.x - 30" y="$canvasEndY - 150" xscale="50" yscale="40" />
        <annotation id="tom-user-icon" type="image" url="http://static.fusioncharts.com/sampledata/images/snickrs.png" x="$xaxis.label.1.x - 26" y="$canvasEndY - 141" xscale="48" yscale="38" />
        <annotation id="Milton-user-icon" type="image" url="http://static.fusioncharts.com/sampledata/images/coffee_crisp.png" x="$xaxis.label.2.x - 22" y="$canvasEndY - 134" xscale="43" yscale="36" />
        <annotation id="Brian-user-icon" type="image" url="http://static.fusioncharts.com/sampledata/images/100grand.png" x="$xaxis.label.3.x - 22" y="$canvasEndY - 131" xscale="43" yscale="35" />
    </annotationgroup>
</annotations>
```

So I have tried this myself, but it is giving me an error :

```
 //Peak Images
        strXML += "<annotations>";
        strXML += "<annotationgroup>";

         foreach (var cat in CalcList)
        {
            if (cat.isPeak)
            {
                strXML += "<annotation id='Test' type='image' url='http://static.fusioncharts.com/sampledata/userimages/1.png' x='$dataset.0.set." + iPeakCount +".x-" + cat.Elevation + "' y='$dataset.0.set." + iPeakCount + ".y-" + cat.Accumulated_Length + "'/>  ";
                iPeakCount++;
            }
        }

        strXML += "<annotationgroup>";
        strXML += "<annotations>";
```

But I am getting "Invalid data" back from the FusionChart.

We have done something similar using `json` as a test previously, so we know it is possible - Except I want to do it using XML(Which I have done), but just have no idea how to do it :( - Below is the snippet of code :

```
                    "annotations": {
                        "groups": [
                            {
                                "id": "anchor-highlight",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "high-star",
                                        "type": "image",
                                        "url": "http://static.fusioncharts.com/sampledata/userimages/1.png",
                                        "x": "$dataset.0.set.11.x-25",
                                        "y": "$dataset.0.set.11.y-25"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "high-star",
                                        "type": "image",
                                        "url": "http://static.fusioncharts.com/sampledata/userimages/1.png",
                                        "x": "$dataset.0.set.6.x-25",
                                        "y": "$dataset.0.set.6.y-25"
                                    }
                        ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

Am I completely missing the plot or what am I missing ?

Please go gentle on me, this is all new to me and am struggling quite a bit.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: So my first issue is that my closing <Annotationsgroup> and <Annotations> tags were wrong. It should be </annotationsgroup> and </annotations>. I am specifically not updating this on my post as something this simple can cause many hours of pain. When I find the solution I will post the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself again...

Below is the code :

```
strXML += "<annotations>";
strXML += "<annotationgroup>";

        foreach (var cat in CalcList)
        {
            if (cat.isPeak)
            {
                strXML += "<annotation id='Peak" + iPeakCount + "' type='image' url='/Images/Peak.png' x='$dataset.2.set." + iPeakCount + ".x-12' y='$dataset.2.set." + iPeakCount + ".y-12' xscale='6' yscale='6' />";
                iPeakCount++;
            }
        }

strXML += "</annotationgroup>";
strXML += "</annotations>";
```

You will notice the following :

`x='$dataset.2.set." + iPeakCount + ".x-12' y='$dataset.2.set." + iPeakCount + ".y-12'`

The number 2 means it must display on my 3rd dataset(Datasets start at 0). Below is one of the datasets :

```
strXML += "<dataset  drawline= '1' seriesname= 'Elevation' color= '#0045ff' anchorsides= '0' anchorradius= '0' anchorbgcolor= '#0045ff' anchorbordercolor= '#0045ff'>";

        foreach (var cat in CalcList)
        {
            if (cat.Elevation >= 0)
            {
                strXML += "<set y='" + cat.Elevation + "' x='" + cat.Accumulated_Length + "'/>";
            }
        }

strXML += "</dataset>";
```

Hope this helps someone else...